# How do I programmatically simulate a tap event on a view in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

I am writing some code to do some automated UI testing of my NativeScript app.  The code will be hosted within the app itself, so I need to be able to drive UI events from the javascript code.  Specifically, I need to be able to programmatically cause a tap event to occur on a view.

Some searches on Google haven't turned up any good way to do this.  I saw a couple of similar questions containing suggestions to just call the tap event handler function directly, but this won't work when the arguments object is needed, because the direct call won't contain the NativeScript generated arguments object.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using vanilla or ng2?

Comment: Vanilla NativeScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do it.
1. You can use NativeScript-Dom (Disclaimer I'm the author); and then you can easily do this:

```
var x = getElementById("blah"); 
x.notify({eventName: "tap", object: x});
```

or

`runAgainstTagName("Buttons",  function(elem) { 
      elem.notify({eventName: "tap", object: elem}
 );`

or `getElementsByTagName`/`getElementsByClassName`, or `runAgainstId`/`RunAgainstClassName`
or you can use even use the built in `.getViewById("blah");`

Any one of those to find the element(s).  Then use the `.notify` to send the tap event to it.

Comment: The `notify()` method is exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nathanael does `notify` only work if the event is set to the view in `xml`? I have attached the `swipe` event to a view in `onNavigatedTo` and event won't fire from `notify`. Also calling `view.hasListener({eventName: "swipe"})` returns `false`, but I know the event is bound.

Comment: Come to think of it, what would be the `swipe.direction` here? Is there a default?

Comment: You can use whatever you want technically; but I think the normal values are  "left" and "right".  But you can check the source for it..

Comment: How can I use this in nativescript-angular?